# HtmlAgilityPack How to replace this text cf.example

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I would like to know how to get into a string a value. 
For example, I want to put HELLO value in a string but i do not know how to do.. :( someone could help me please?

```
<div class="position" >
<span class="cvetica" style="font-size: 24px">
<label style="font-size: 30px">11.522</label>
HELLO      
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your particular example is fairly easy - the latest HtmlAgilityPack also supports Linq so this would work:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("test.html");

var spanNode = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("span")
                    .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"]!=null && x.Attributes["class"].Value == "cvetica")
                    .FirstOrDefault();

if (spanNode != null)
{
    string text = spanNode.InnerText; 
    string  textHello = spanNode.ChildNodes
                                .Where(x => x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text)
                                .Last().InnerText;
}
```

Note that the first output would not be what you might expect, since there is no direct enclosing element for the string "HELLO" you will get the HTML of the label as well - you can work around this by just retrieving the last text node.

Comment: @JérémieDjidjiL'Amoroso: Updated with example to retrieve last text node directly